# Bootstrap 4 IE not taking col-sm-12 on card-img-overlay

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I created a cta with image and text overlay using the bootstrap card-img-overlay class. Also added a div with dark low opacity to make the text brighter. Everything work good on all browsers except IE 11.

Q1:
 **where is the column width breaking in IE, i don't think its my css that's 
 causing this part. is it a known bootstrap 4 issue?**

Q2:
**how to fix the overlay div to show on top of the image like chrome and other browsers. Is there a better approch that works for both?**

broke IE IMAGE
[image]

Chome and other browsers that are working good
[image]

```css
.dnow-regionsContent .overlay-div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.dnow-regionsContent img {
    max-height: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>slick slider</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <section class="dnow-regionsWrap">
      <div class="dnow-regionsContent">
         <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
            <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
            <div class="overlay-div"></div>
            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-center container">
               <div class="row  mb-5">
                  <div class=" col-sm-12 text-content">
                     <h2 class="card-title ">
                        Canada
                     </h2>
                     <p class="">
                        Viewl all Location Viewl all Location
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add your codes.

Comment: @DogukanCavus srry submitted too quickly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The actual reason:**

It's **not `col-sm-12`**, but the **`d-flex`** on `card-img-overlay` which makes your design look not proper in IE.

**Why?**

When `display:flex` is applied to an element, the immediate child *(i.e. the flex items)* would need some width to be specified or else they would not expand or take up enough space as we require unless content is not sufficient enough.

In your case we have `d-flex` along `card-img-overlay` so the immediate child (i.e. flex item) of it `.row`, would not be having `100%` width. Now for `col-sm-12` column, `100%` would be full horizontal space that is with its parent (`.row`) which is not itself wide enough. That's the real issue here.

**Solution:**

1. Give `100%` width to `.row`, you may use class of Bootstrap 4 `w-100`.

   - This could have been the real solution to your issue/query but few things are still needed to get the look you want, as you have it in other browsers.
2. Giving `position: absolute` does not work alone, the smart browsers would know what to do, but the other ones would need offset values like `top` & `left`. In your case with value as `0`.
3. Finally image with actual dimensions to attributes `width` and `height` of `<img>` tag, here in your case it would be `width="1200"` & `height="800"`.

So basically bootstrap has nothing to do with this issue, it's just the flow of markup and CSS properties.

**Side Note:**

I hope the above steps helped you to clear issue or understand it. I would suggest to always have `width` and `height` attributes for an `<img>` tag so that the browsers(old ones) would know to make that specific size of the block on a page.

```css
.dnow-regionsContent .overlay-div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
    /*Added*/
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.dnow-regionsContent img {
    max-height: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>slick slider</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <section class="dnow-regionsWrap">
      <div class="dnow-regionsContent">
         <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
            <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1" width="1200" height="800" alt="">
            <div class="overlay-div"></div>
            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-center container">
               <div class="row mb-5 w-100">
                  <div class=" col-sm-12 text-content">
                     <h2 class="card-title ">
                        Canada
                     </h2>
                     <p class="">
                        Viewl all Location Viewl all Location
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

It was not you, it was IE.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: that  works,  great explanation on both issues - thanks

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I've not got anyway of testing IE.

But i've used your example and taken it to the grass roots of [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/card/).

I have modified your css and html to use `:before` to overlay the image with your black opaque style. I apply this on `.card-img-overlay` and any child elements will naturally appear above the `:before` pseudo style.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1" class="card-img" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col align-self-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

**SASS/CSS**

```
.card-img-overlay {
  overflow: hidden;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }

}
```

Try this fiddle in IE... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/xm4ude0L/

If this still doesn't work in IE still then you are going to have to be old school and find a work around. If it was me, I would output a browser body class, and control the problem for the IE users using css. You have not mentioned how you generate your html so I cant advise on a browser body class function.

Or just use [browser happy](https://browsehappy.com/) to promote better ways of web browsing to force visiting users to up their game and get with the times :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary stuff going on here.

Here is a snippet that works in IE.

Also for whatever reason your img link did not work in IE, so I replaced it with another image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>slick slider</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <section class="dnow-regionsWrap">
      <div class="dnow-regionsContent">    
         <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
          <img src="https://cdn2.outdoorphotographer.com/2018/04/DShow_Echoconfl-824x548.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="card-img-overlay align-items-center d-flex">
              <div class="card-body ">
                <h2 class="card-title">
                 Canada
                </h2>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Viewl all Location Viewl all Location
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
               
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap 4 uses the flex property for the column. This property as far as I know is not entirely compatible with IE. Also IE was discontinued by Microsoft, I would not worry about giving support.

Comment: IE still has about 3% market share (as per http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share#monthly-201712-201812-bar) so you cant count it out completely yet. Progressive enchancemnt is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: we still have to support IE 11, ms still gives update for 11